# Base point free linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a (compact) Riemann surface. Let $D$ be a divisor. In Rick Miranda's book on Riemann surfaces, on page 160, there is a bijection between

1. Base-point-free linear systems of dimension $n$ on $X$
2. holomorphic maps $\phi: X \to \mathbb P^n$ with nondegenerate image, up to linear coordinate changes

Suppose $|D|$ is nonempty and corresponds to a basis $f_0, \dots f_n$ in $L(D)$. Without assuming $|D|$ is base-point-free, I can still get a map $\phi: X \to \mathbb P^n$ by $p \mapsto [f_0(p): \dots : f_n(p)]$. If you're worried about common poles or zeros at $p$, we can essentially divide or multiply by some power of $z$ in local coordinates with $p$ corresponding to $0$ (see Lemma 4.2 on page 154).

***So why do we need base-point-free? Don't all nonempty linear systems give meromorphic functions into projective space? Why do we need to bother with linear systems to get maps into projective space? Shouldn't just having $n+1$ meromorphic functions be enough?***

To prove the bijection above I do indeed require the linear system to be base-point-free.

Comment: @Hoot I thought linear systems with basepoints give holomorphic maps into projective space. Are you also implying that if the linear system is base-point-free, then the corresponding holomorphic map is actually a morphism in the category of varieties?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't think about the analytic category very much. I didn't realize that was at issue here.

Comment: I forgot you were in the one-dimensional and smooth case. That's a bit special! You can always extend such maps. That's his point. I do worry about trying to define a map by just throwing in $n+1$ meromorphic functions. I think you want to try and write down what that would mean.

Comment: @Hoot That's Lemma 4.2 in his book. The map is $p \mapsto [f_0(p): \dots : f_n(p)]$. If you have a common pole or zero, then you can "cancel it" by multiplying by $z$ to some power after choosing a local coordinate near $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D$ be a divisor with $|D|\neq\emptyset$. Then we may replace $D$ with a linearly equivalent effective divisor and assume that $D$ is effective. Then base points of $D$ are contained in the support of $D$ and if $B$ is the divisor of base points, then $|D|=|D-B|$.So, the map given by $|D|$ is the same as the one given by the base point free divisor $D-B$.

So, the correct way of saying what Miranda says is that 1 is equivalent to 2 with an additional condition on 2, namely, $\phi^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))=\mathcal{O}_X(D)$.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be correct to say all nonempty linear systems give a holomorphic map, but we care about the linear systems that are base point free because they fit nicely in this bijection?

Comment: Any bunch (non-empty) of meromorphic functions give a holomorphic map from a smooth curve (aka Riemann Surface) to a suitable projective space. The bijection (with my extra condition) works only for base point free linear systems.

Comment: Thanks. Then why should we worry about linear systems? Why not just talk about bunches of meromorphic functions? Linear systems seem rather complicated to me.

Comment: @hwong557 I think there are a lot of things being used here that are special to the one-dimensional case (which is why I've said so many wrong things in the comments above).